# What happens if the batsman hits the gloves of the keeper just prior to playing a shot which resulted in the shot being impeded?

Tags: rules, cricket

What happens if the batsman hits the gloves of the keeper just prior to playing a shot which resulted in the shot being impeded? Should it be a dead ball or should any result - either a dismissal, do ball or runs stand?

Note - the intentions of the wicket keeper (it was not deliberate) or the gloves being in front of the wicket (they were not) are not of concern.

Answer (score 2):

I have taken a long hard look at the laws and can see nothing here about this specifically.

However if the gloves aren't in-front of the stumps and the wicket keeper didn't deliberately obstruct the batsman I would play on.

If there isn't a decision to be made then status quo persists and play on and the ball stands as played.